# Need Best Practice Assistance, or RegEx advice to create Image Sprite Mappings to CSS

Tags: html, css, regex, dreamweaver, sprite

Using Compass, I am generating Image Sprites and CSS.

This works great, however, since I am generating numerous sprite images and CSS, mapping the image to the class names can take quite some time for myself and the other developers.

I have currently created some regular expressions in DreamWeaver to allow me to generate an HTML page that displays the images, along with their corresponding class names, however, it is not the best layout as it just lists them in floating divs, and I would prefer to display them in either a tabular format using tables, or groups of 7 divs per row.

My code currently looks like...

```
...
<body>
<table>

<td class="sprite-container">
  <div class="sprite-image myimage001"></div>
  <div class="sprite-label">myimage001</div>
</td>

<td ... and so on...
```

I would like to either have a regular expression to wrap each group of 7 instances of the TD content with TR tags so that it will appear neat and tidy. (I've also done using just divs, etc, but since I am doing manually, this has been the easiest to maintain)

I have been currently doing this manually... counting every 30 rows from a td group and inserting the  tags... this is monotonous, and since I am working with over 800 classes, takes quite some time to do... and I have to REDO every time I regenerate the sprites! ugh!

Alternatively, I am open to other suggestions as to how to better approach this...  i.e. a script, tool, ruby gem, regular expression, etc..   Thanks in advance for any assistance.  I hope that someone else finds this useful.

Note:
The Process I currently use is I copy the CSS file into a new document.
I remove any erroneous CSS (multiple sets).
I run the following regular expressions via find-replace

FIND >  `\{[\w\W]*?\}`

REPLACE > *`NOTHING`*

FIND >  `.(sprite[\S]*)\s`

REPLACE >

```
<td class="sprite-container">
  <div class="sprite-image $1"></div>
  <div class="sprite-label">$1</div>
 </td>
```

Then I do my manual editing by adding the CSS references, HTML tags, etc to get it to display properly.

Thanks again in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to use a DIV instead of a TD.

```
<DIV class="sprite-container">
  <div class="sprite-image $1"></div>
  <div class="sprite-label">$1</div>
 </DIV>
```

Then use CSS to style the sprite-container. All that's required is that sprite container be position: relative and float: left.

```
.sprite-container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: .5em;
    min-width: 50px; min-height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Then use CSS :nth-child to make every element that is at the start of a new line of 7 spite-container's force a break in the floating layout.

```
.sprite-container:nth-child(7n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/KQ59S/

Comment: I had never tried nth-child before, and it worked perfectly!  Thank you!